# Firebase auth error when uploading audio file to Google Cloud

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, jwt

We have an webapp that uses an external auth provider (Clerk) and gives us a JWT with all the firebase credentials. Everything works perfectly except on an exam page where users are spending at least 45 min. The INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED message usually but not always means that if I try to submit audio it will fail. The audio goes to an appspot bucket and it works fine for at least the first 30 minutes on the page.

It's very inconsistent.

I'm not sure exactly what code to share, but I'm happy to add more.

[image: Firebase error]

Comment: What I think is happening is the token from Google is expiring. I'm currently trying to use getIdToken() to force the token to refresh. It seems to work in my local, but on firebase it fails with auth/network-request-failed